# Get woocommerce 4 product custom attribute value in WP Lister for Amazon

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I want to get value of product custom attributes (brand) in plugin options of plugin wp-lister for amazon, the code provided by the developer is for global attribute and is following

ref url for code: https://www.wplab.com/plugins/wp-lister-for-amazon/api/#wpla_custom_values

Can we modify any of the above two codes to get the value of custom product attribute of products (Brand - as in screenshot below) instead of global attribute. Curently by using the above codes the custom attribute value is not displayed and only global attribute value is considered.

Product Custom Attribute Name
[image: product custom attribute name - Brand]

Plugin Options

[image: plugin options]

Code Example 1
[image: code example 1 - can be copied by visiting the top URL]

Code Example 2
[image: code example 2 - can be copied by visiting the top URL]

Comment: unable to paste code here therefore need to visit the plugin documentation site